# Ajax filter on custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, admin-ajax

I created an ajax filter on custom post type filter is working fine when I select 10-12 filters but after that admin-ajax.php file gone to pending, I don't know what is the issue.

Website url : http://mustafafazal.com/intranet/carrier-filter-tool/
you can check this issue in dev mode > network in chrome.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Rso.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzug8.png

```
function misha_filter_function(){
 $nested_condition = array();
if (isset($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['state'])){

            $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                            'relation' => 'AND',
                                            array(
                                                    'key' => 'state',
                                                    'value'   => $_POST['state'],
                                                    //'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                                ),  
                                        );                      
}
if (isset($_POST['age']) && !empty($_POST['age'])){
            $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                            'relation' => 'AND',
                                            array(
                                                    'key'       => 'age_min',
                                                    'value'     => $_POST['age'],
                                                    'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                                    'compare'   => '<='

                                                ),
                                            array(
                                                'key'       => 'age_max',
                                                'value'     => $_POST['age'],
                                                'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                                'compare'   => '>='

                                                )


                                        );              
}
if (isset($_POST['months']) && !empty($_POST['months'])){

            $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                            'relation' => 'AND',
                                            array(
                                                    'key'       => 'months_of_exp_min',
                                                    'value'     => $_POST['months'],
                                                    'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                                    'compare'   => '<='
                                                ),  
                                            array(
                                                    'key'       => 'months_of_exp_max',
                                                    'value'     => $_POST['months'],
                                                    'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                                    'compare'   => '>='
                                                )   
                                        );                      
}

if (isset($_POST['driver_type']) && !empty($_POST['driver_type'])){
    // Get the selected options
    $valueFront1 = $_POST['driver_type'];
    // echo print_r($valueFront); die();
    // Build the meta query based on the selected options
    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
    foreach( $valueFront1 as $item1 ){
        $nested_condition[] = array(
            'key'     => 'driver_type',
            'value'   => $item1,
            //'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );
    }

}
if (isset($_POST['division_requested']) && !empty($_POST['division_requested'])){
    // Get the selected options
    $valueFront2 = $_POST['division_requested'];
    // echo print_r($valueFront); die();
    // Build the meta query based on the selected options
    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
    foreach( $valueFront2 as $item2 ){
        $nested_condition[] = array(
            'key'     => 'division',
            'value'   => $item2,
            //'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );
    }

}
if (isset($_POST['freight_type']) && !empty($_POST['freight_type'])){
    // Get the selected options
    $valueFront3 = $_POST['freight_type'];
    // echo print_r($valueFront); die();
    // Build the meta query based on the selected options
    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
    foreach( $valueFront3 as $item3 ){
        $nested_condition[] = array(
            'key'     => 'freight_type',
            'value'   => $item3,
            //'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );
    }

}
if (isset($_POST['home_time_requested']) && !empty($_POST['home_time_requested'])){
    // Get the selected options
    $valueFront4 = $_POST['home_time_requested'];
    // echo print_r($valueFront); die();
    // Build the meta query based on the selected options
    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
    foreach( $valueFront4 as $item4 ){
        $nested_condition[] = array(
            'key'     => 'home_time',
            'value'   => $item4,
            //'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );
    }

}
if (isset($_POST['additional_options']) && !empty($_POST['additional_options'])){
    // Get the selected options
    $valueFront5 = $_POST['additional_options'];
    // echo print_r($valueFront); die();
    // Build the meta query based on the selected options
    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
    foreach( $valueFront5 as $item5 ){
        $nested_condition[] = array(
            'key'     => 'additional_options',
            'value'   => $item5,
            //'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );
    }

}
if (isset($_POST['sign_on_bonus_requested']) && !empty($_POST['sign_on_bonus_requested'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'sign_on_bonus',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['sign_on_bonus_requested']
                                            //'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                        )
                                );                      
}

if (isset($_POST['careless_years']) && !empty($_POST['careless_years'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'careless_min',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['careless_years'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '<='
                                        ),
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'careless_max',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['careless_years'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '>='
                                        )   
                                );                      
}

if (isset($_POST['reckless_years']) && !empty($_POST['reckless_years'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'recklace_min',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['reckless_years'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '<='
                                        ),
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'recklace_max',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['reckless_years'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '>='
                                        )   
                                );                      
}
if (isset($_POST['dui']) && !empty($_POST['dui'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'dui_in_cmv',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['dui'],
                                            //'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                        )   
                                );                      
}

if (isset($_POST['dui_years']) && !empty($_POST['dui_years'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'dui_yrs_min',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['dui_years'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '<='
                                        ),
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'dui_yrs_max',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['dui_years'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '>='
                                        )   
                                );                      
}

if (isset($_POST['moving_violations']) && !empty($_POST['moving_violations'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'no_of_moving_violations',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['moving_violations'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '='
                                        )   
                                );                      
}
if (isset($_POST['dot_recordable']) && !empty($_POST['dot_recordable'])){ 

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'dot_recordable_min',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['dot_recordable'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '<='
                                        ),  
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'dot_recordable_max',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['dot_recordable'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '>='
                                        )   
                                );                      
}
if (isset($_POST['preventable']) && !empty($_POST['preventable'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'preventable_min',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['preventable'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '<='
                                        ),
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'preventable_max',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['preventable'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '>='
                                        )   
                                );                      
}
if (isset($_POST['job_years']) && !empty($_POST['job_years'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => '#_of_jobs_min',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['job_years'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '<='
                                        ),  
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => '#_of_jobs_max',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['job_years'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '>='
                                        )   
                                );                      
}

if (isset($_POST['terminated']) && !empty($_POST['terminated'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'terminated',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['terminated'],
                                            //'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                        )
                                );                      
}

if (isset($_POST['safety_reasons']) && !empty($_POST['safety_reasons'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'safety_term',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['safety_reasons'],
                                            //'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                        )
                                );                      
}

if (isset($_POST['last_job']) && !empty($_POST['last_job'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'last_job_term',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['last_job'],
                                            //'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                        )   
                                );                      
}

if (isset($_POST['alcohol_test']) && !empty($_POST['alcohol_test'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'failed_da_test',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['alcohol_test'],
                                            //'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                        )
                                );                      
}
if (isset($_POST['how_long']) && !empty($_POST['how_long'])){

    $nested_condition[] =   array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'failed_when_min',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['how_long'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '<='
                                        ),  
                                    array(
                                            'key'       => 'failed_when_max',
                                            'value'     => $_POST['how_long'],
                                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                            'compare'   => '>='
                                        )
                                );                      
}




$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'carrier',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'meta_query'    => $nested_condition
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
//echo $the_query->request; die();
?> 
<?php
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
       ?>
        <div class="carrier-box">
           <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
           <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Website</a>
       </div>
        <?php          
    endwhile;


    endif;
    ?>

    <?php
     wp_reset_query();   // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
<?php
    die();

}


add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');
```

Comment: As a test, I checked a bunch of random options and submitted the form several times. It always worked, all ajax requests returned status 200.

Comment: but its not working in my case.

Comment: is it server issue?

Comment: Maybe. Hard to say without more details. For example, how many posts are there in the `posts` table? What plugins are installed on your site? What are you doing to optimize your site's performance? Also, does this still happen if you're using a different browser? There are too many variables here, as you can see. You'll need to do some research.

Comment: there are only 40 posts on the backend

Comment: i will check by changing browser.